# mongodb configuration file issue on Mac OS X

Tags: mongodb

The docs say that I can configure mongodb startup using the command mongod -f /etc/mongodb.conf.  I created the file as follows which works fine:

```
dbpath = /Applications/MAMP/db/mongodb
```

But if I add a port as follows it exits with an error that the port does not exist

```
dbpath = /Applications/MAMP/db/mongodb
port = 22123
```

Now if I remove the port = 22123 and use the following command it works fine:

```
mongod -f /etc/mongodb.conf --port 22123
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you copy past the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.

The file was using a CR (Classic Mac) delimiter instead of LF (Unix) delimiter. Looks like these files need to use Unix format. I re-saved the file using Unix format and now it works.